# How do I get the base url to map to index.html in tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat

I have a welcome-file-list in the conf/web.xml file as per the default configuration.

I have a ROOT application with ROOT/index.html in it. for example.com/index.html the page is displayed correctly, but http://example.com does not work (404 error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was a corrupted web.xml file.

```
<
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
-
```